# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I use this function to check number:

```
def numValid(code):
    LOOKUP = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
    code = reduce(str.__add__, filter(str.isdigit, code))
    evens = sum(int(i) for i in code[-1::-2])
    odds = sum(LOOKUP[int(i)] for i in code[-2::-2])
    return ((evens + odds) % 10 == 0)
```

I call it using `numValid(242344)` where `242344` is `dtype: int64`.

Why I get error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable on the line:

filter(str.isdigit, code))
```

Comment: why not usign a regex ?

Comment: Why do you need to check if the passed in number is made up of digits at all anyway? what integer do you know of that isn't made up of digits?

Comment: `filter` takes a function and applies it to an iterable (e.g. a sequence like a string or a `list`), emitting only those elements of the iterable for which the function returns `True`. But an integer isn't iterable.

Comment: apart for the debatable use of your function you can (probably) fix it using `code = str(code)` in place of the ugly `reduce`

Comment: If you are calling numValid(242344) then the value passed is a Python int and yet you seem to be trying to process it as a string. Maybe you could explain the ultimate purpose of this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers aren't sequences - they're just atomic things, so you can't iterate over them. It looks like you're trying to apply a string function to each digit - you'll need to convert `code` to a string (i.e. `str(code)`).

Comment: So I need convert it into str right?

Comment: @George can you explain the logic of your algorithm? A decent answer will depend on what exactly you try to achieve